# nmcli device status filter specific interface

Tags: nmcli

Is it possible to print the status of DEVICE enp0s9 without using egrep?

```
$ nmcli device status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s3  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
enp0s9  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 2 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --                 
$
```

I want similar output by using `nmcli` command only and not with external command such as `egrep`

```
$ nmcli device status | egrep 'D|9'
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s9  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 2 
$
```

Comment: According to the [manual](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html), the `status` command has no arguments. But perhaps you like the output of `nmcli -f GENERAL.DEVICE,GENERAL.TYPE,GENERAL.STATE,GENERAL.CONNECTION dev show enp0s9`.

Comment: You can try this ``` nmcli device show [<ifname>] ``` 
for example ``` $ nmcli device show enp3s1 ```

Comment: `nmcli -g` will be easier to parse than `nmcli -f` but otherwise I don't see anyway to filter the rows of output.  I think the ncmli devs expect you to use grep on that output.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help others once that are comming one year after question...

```
[user@host]# nmcli -g general.state device show enp0s9
100 (connected)
```

nmcli shows one data per line.
To get same data you provided, this is the way:

```
[user@host]# nmcli -m multiline -g general.device,general.type,general.state,general.connection device show eth0
GENERAL.DEVICE:enp0s9
GENERAL.TYPE:ethernet
GENERAL.STATE:100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:Wired connection 2
```

Removing `-m multiline` you will receive default format without keyword prefix:

```
[user@host]# nmcli -g general.device,general.type,general.state,general.connection device show eth0
enp0s9
ethernet
100 (connected)
Wired connection 2
```

Omitting option **-g general.state** will give you all available data like this:

```
[user@host]# nmcli device show eth0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s9
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         B6:20:89:30:E8:03
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.10.0.100/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.10.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.10.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 10.10.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             1.1.1.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             1.1.1.2
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::652c:ff98:a178:aa73/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be exactly what the question is asking for.  Can the user specify `-g` multiple times; e.g., to get general.type *and* general.state? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.